# Android get file using path (in String format)

Tags: java, android

My app needs to get an existing file for processing. Now I have the path of the file in String format, how can I get the File with it? Is it correct to do this:

`File fileToSave = new File(dirOfTheFile);`

Here dirOfTheFile is the path of the file. If I implement it in this way, will I get the existing file or the system will create another file for me?

Answer (score 2):

That's what you want to do. If the file exists you'll get it. Otherwise you'll create it. You can check whether the file exists by calling `fileToSave.exists()` on it and act appropriately if it does not.

The `new` keyword is creating a `File` object in code, not necessarily a new file on the device.

I would caution you to not use hardcoded paths if you are for dirOfFile. For example, if you're accessing external storage, call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of hardcoding /sdcard.

Answer (score 2):

The `File` object is just a *reference* to a file (a wrapper around the path of the file); creating a new `File` object does not actually create or read the file; to do that, use [FileInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) to read, [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to write, or the various File helper methods (like `exists()`, `createNewFile()`, etc.) for example to actually perform operations on the path in question. Note that, as others have pointed out, you should use one of the utilities provided by the system to locate directories on the internal or external storage, depending on where you want your files.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
File fileToSave = new File(dirOfTheFile);
if(fileToSave.exists())
{
 // the file exists. use it
} else {
// create file here
}
```

if parent folder is not there you may have to call `fileToSave.getParentFile().mkdirs()` to create parent folders